# Is there a way to get get all mentions of a certain pattern and following values in a string in python

Tags: python

Im trying to get all values in a string that's looks like the following:

`example = 'jnkfksieufsieufsejfuies Title="Something" daowijdaowdnobngfoinbijfgh Title="something else"`

is there a way to get the values following the Title variable in the string.

I thought to use some sort method to get all Title mentions in the string, then be able to get the following values but im not sure how that is possible in python.

Im guessing i could use some pattern regognizion from the "re" dependency

Comment: Yes, module "re" is the usual approach. You can use https://regex101.com to play around with regular expressions (set flavor to "Python").

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` with a pattern having a group to match what's after the `Title`

```
example = 'jnkfksieufsieufsejfuies Title="Something" daowijdaowdnobngfoinbijfgh Title="something else"'
titles = re.findall(f'Title="([^"]+)"', example)
print(titles)  # ['Something', 'something else']
```

Comment: Is there a way to read up on what all the symbols used in the re.findall do? Like for example "[^"]+"

Comment: always search for documentation of the package you're using: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @pvpb0t learn about regexes, I won't re-copy the websites that does it very well like regex101.com or many others